# Adding Power Series - Properties of Power Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, factorial

I'm trying to add two power series which are given as two functions
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n}x^n $$
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{n!}{n^n}x^n $$

I can't seem to find the power series of:
$$\frac{1}{2}(f(x)+g(x))$$

I have no idea what I'm doing and attempted:
$$\frac{(\frac{n!}{n^n}x^n+(-1)^n\frac{n!}{n^n}x^n)}{2}$$

Which simplifies to but isn't quite right:
$$\frac{n!((-1)^n+1)x^n}{2n^n}$$

Any help and guidance on the right path would be so very appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think that what you have done isn't right?

Comment: This is a set of problems I've been practicing for a calc II course, the online grading system has marked it as incorrect. I've gone over this problem multiple times formatting my answer differently each time and I still haven't gotten it.

Comment: (Note that $g(x)=f(-x)$, so you're finding the even part of $f$.) Have you tried this form? $$\sum\frac{(2n)!}{(2n)^{(2n)}}x^{(2n)}$$ It is equivalent to yours, since $$\frac{(-1)^n+1}{2}=\begin{cases}1,\quad n\text{ is even}\\0,\quad n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you so very much, this is the accepted solution.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how you arrived at this solution. Would you mind linking a webpage, video, or explain how this works? Thank you very much regardless.

Comment: $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{(-1)^n+1}{2}a_n=(1)a_0+(0)a_1+(1)a_2+(0)a_3+(1)a_4+(0)a_5+\cdots$$ $$=a_0+a_2+a_4+\cdots=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_{2n}$$

Comment: Ah. Of course. Thank you so very much for your time and patience, I appreciate your help!